# about:blank#blocked on <a href="file:///XXX">Link</a> (Markdown Page)

Tags: html, google-chrome, markdown, href

In a Markdown Page (Microsoft TFS Wiki)
I try crate A tag for `file` link:

```
<a href="file:///C:/temp\file.txt">file.txt</a>
```

On click (Chrome), I got

```
about:blank#blocked
```

[image]

Comment: Add an atribute `download` to the `<a>`

Comment: @Roy still not working

Comment: Are you sure that the `href` is correct? add `target="_self"` and try again

Comment: @Roy still.....

Comment: I can't help if you don't make a working demo... sorry mate, i need more references to discover the problem

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Chrome-specific issue with protocol **file:**, Opera and Firefox display blank page too. 
When I want to browse HTML files on my localhost, I have to access them via protocol **http:** instead.
For instance when I want to see `C:\temp\file.html` in Chrome, I will make a virtual directory in my local Apache host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/temp
    ServerName temp.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

and add this line to `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 temp.localhost
```

Now I can see the file in browsers at URL **http://temp.localhost/file.html**