# How do I create a hyperlink for a filepath in powerbi?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to create a file path link in either a table or a tooltip on a map in Powerbi. After doing some research "File" is an acceptable input for the "Web URL" data category. But for some reason when I try to use it as a hyperlink in the browser, it will not work. Below are some pictures of the problem.

[image]

[image]

What is the best way to fix this issue? Do I need to change how I string in the file path?

Comment: I gave it a try. file:///  and file:// both failed... Looks like it may be broken, or an option in the setting needs to be switched but I don't see such option.

Comment: According to this 2017 update (https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-may-feature-summary/#urlTables), it appears to state that most browsers will not be able to open the link and you have to copy and paste it (Lame!) but what browsers supports it? Edge and explorer (Microsoft products) appear to not work as well which is pretty funny.

Comment: Check my answer... very lame, but there for a security reason I guess. Someone could link file://c/windows/sytem/cmd.exe%20someparam I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I found definitive answer - it doesn't work as one would expect. It appears it only used to work on Edge, however Edge has switched to Chromium underneath and this capability has not been carried over since it is a potential security risk.

If I navigate from Power BI Service and try and right click to open the link, I get. `about:blank#blocked`

[Here is the post I found](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/File-URL-on-Button-Action/td-p/1207216)

[And here is the idea you need to vote for:](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=206a05bb-fa70-41da-9bda-ea385a8dee59) - Extract below.

Currently open a local file from Desktop is not possible and from browser is very tedious as explained on May 2017 update:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-may-feature-summary/#urlTables

"If you want to use file URLs, there are some limitations. They will not open in the Power BI Desktop, only in web browsers. For most browsers, you will need to right click on the link, copy the link address, and paste the URL in a new tab"

It will be great if can be improved the way to open the files in same way as with web images or files (http://).

Comment: is there anyway to unblock the browser from right clicking it into a new tab?

Comment: I dont think so, not easily at least https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55101162/aboutblankblocked-on-a-href-file-xxxlink-a-markdown-page  and not sure if the following applies in new Edge https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0face535-3c7a-4658-be34-6c376322ca34/microsoft-edge-cant-open-local-domains

Comment: What about a work around such as using a different link type maybe (Ex. "http:") or even using an image url?

Comment: Place the files you want to access in Office 365 / Onedrive and link to them via http...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I create pdf files on a Monthly basis to share with my users. In this case file url are working well.